# Nonlinear optimization using Lagrange Duality

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I've been trying to solve the following exercise: I need to maximize the function
$$
f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_1^2 + 6x_2 + 4x_3^2
$$
with constraints
$$
2x_1 + x_2 + 4x_3 \leq 10\\
x_1, x_3 \geq 0\\
x_2 \in [0, 1]
$$
using the Lagrangian Dual method. I used the following example https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB9Jy.jpg and tried to replicate it on my problem. Firstly, I changed the maximization into minimization by considering $-f(x_1, x_2, x_3)$. Then formed the Lagrangian:
$$
L(x_1, x_2, x_3) = -x_1^2 - 6x_2 - 4x_3^2 + \lambda (2x_1 +x_2 + 4x_3 - 10).
$$
Now the Lagrangian dual function is, after grouping same variables:
\begin{align}
\theta(\lambda) &= \min_{x_1 \geq 0} \{-x_1^2 + 2\lambda x_1\}\\ &+\min_{x_2\in [0, 1]} \{-6x_2 + \lambda x_2\} \\ &+ \min_{x_3 \geq 0} \{-4x_3^2 + 4\lambda x_3\} - 10\lambda.
\end{align}
For the next step I need to resolve these minima in the function but they have negative coefficients at the quadratic member and I cannot resolve them.

Comment: The constraints imply that $x_1 \le 5$ and $x_3 \le 2.5$, so each $\min$ is bounded.

Comment: @RobPratt you cannot consider such implied bounds for computing the dual. The value of the dual is $-\infty$, which does not violate weak duality.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to formulate the dual problem, but that does not give you a solution because strong duality does not hold. You should formulate the KKT conditions.

Comment: @LinAlg, think of the implied bounds as a primal preprocessing step that does not change the feasible region.